# DW5804 (E371) WWAN LTE modem slow performance

Tags: wireless

Dear Ubuntu community,

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as my only OS (in fact, it is the XUbuntu 18.04).

Recently I have installed the DW5804 (E371) PCI-E LTE modem card into my laptop (which is the Dell Latitude E6420 by the way).

It turns out that the modem seems to be working only in GPRS mode - as if no higher speed modes were available. My gkrellm graph shows upto 15-17 KBps on the modem interface in peaks.

What is funny, once I plug in the XUbuntu installation USB stick and reboot the machine from it and run the XUbuntu demo instead of the installation wizard, my modem performs much faster. Not sure if it the LTE speed but I can easily watch some YouTube videos. The Gkrellm shows 500+ KBps on the modem interface.

What can I change in the Network Manager/modem settings to make it work in LTE speeds?

To be honest I do not even know what output I should paste to help you help me resolving my issue.
Let me start off with the usb-devices output from my basic OS:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=05 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=819b Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Novatel Wireless, Inc.
S:  Product=Novatel Wireless HSPA
S:  SerialNumber=012773000360251
C:  #Ifs= 7 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 6 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=qmi_wwan
I:  If#= 7 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=qmi_wwan
```

The mmcli -m 0 shows this:

```
  --------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |            device id: 8e91d2a924c045cb128290c57cbe91349ac23264
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: Novatel Wireless Incorporated
           |                model: 4051
           |             revision: MDM9200-3.32  1  [2011-12-16 10:00:07]
           |         h/w revision: 203F1000
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: 012773000360253
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6
           |              drivers: option1, qmi_wwan
           |               plugin: Dell
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm1
           |                ports: ttyUSB0 (at), ttyUSB1 (qcdm), ttyUSB2 (qcdm), ttyUSB3 (at), 
           |                       cdc-wdm1 (qmi), wwp0s29u1u6i6 (net)
  --------------------------------
  Status   |                 lock: sim-pin2
           |       unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk (10), sim-puk2 (10)
           |                state: disabled
           |          power state: low
           |       signal quality: 0% (cached)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |              current: allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: egsm, dcs, pcs, g850, utran-1, utran-4, utran-6, utran-5, 
           |                       utran-2
           |              current: egsm, dcs, pcs, g850, utran-1, utran-5, utran-2
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: 012773000360253
           |        enabled locks: sim
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: ps-1
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
  --------------------------------
  Bearer   |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/0
```

Please, help.